# Campos na cláusula order by devem ser indexados?

Tags: mysql, índices

Estou lendo bastante a respeito do uso de índices no Mysql. Observei que realmente é necessário saber utilizá-lo no momento certo e nas colunas adequadas, de forma a tornar as consultas mais rápidas e não o contrário.

Agora, imaginem a seguinte consulta:

```
select campoX 
from tabela 
where campoA = 1 
and campoB = 2 
and campoC = 3 
order by campoM
```

Neste caso, criei um índice composto pelas colunas da clausula `where: campoA, campoB, campoC.` (usando esta mesma ordem)

Minha dúvida se diz respeito ao campo do order by. Devo incluir o campoM no final deste mesmo índice para tornar o meu índice viável?

Aproveitando o mesmo raciocínio, se eu utilizasse um group by nesta consulta, também devo incluí-lo neste indice?

Comment: Boa. Enquanto não quero responder isso diretamente (não sou especialista em MySQL), acredito que a resposta será "depende". Se o resultado do filtro em questão deixar poucos resultados o índice não ajuda muito (e adicionará tempo toda vez que você fizer um `insert` ou `update`). O índice ajuda se você espera um grande número de resultados a serem ordenados. A melhor forma de descobrir o que é melhor é adicionar o índice e comparar a *performance* com a versão sem índice para os seus casos de uso.

Comment: Também não sei se respondo porque estou na mesma do @AnthonyAccioly, depende dos dados pode ser interessante no fim ou no começo.